# How do I move the panel in Visual Studio Code to a quadrant?

Tags: visual-studio-code

By default it's on the bottom. You can right click it and move it do the right, but that will only move it to the right of all open files. I would like to move it here:

[image]

You can do this with files. How could I do this with the panel?

Comment: It looks like this isn't supported as of right now, surprisingly.

Comment: @TimothyG. alright thank you.